# How will SQL Server perform this query behind the scenes

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    myTable
WHERE 
    field1 LIKE 'match0' AND
    myfunc(t1.hardwareConfig) LIKE 'match1'
```

Here is my question,

the matching of field1 is fast and quick, but myfunc takes forever to return and I want to make sure that if field1 doesn't match that it doesn't even attempt to do myfunc.

Will SQL just know this or can I make it explicit in my query?

I'm on MSSQL 2000, 2005 and 2008, hopefully there's a common answer.

Comment: What is mysp? It can't be a stored procedure since you can't use them that way.

Comment: err i meant function -- instead of stored procedure.

Comment: Have a look at the other answers aside from the best answer. The answer may well be that you don't need to worry about it: SQL will figure it out for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enforce the order in which conditions are evaluated, use the following approach, because it is documented that CASE preserves the order in which conditions are evaluated.

```
SELECT 
        *
FROM 
        myTable
WHERE 
  CASE WHEN field1 LIKE 'match0' THEN 
    CASE WHEN myfunc(t1.hardwareConfig) LIKE 'match1' 
      THEN 1 
    END 
  END = 1
```

The following article explains it in good detail: [Predicates in SQL](http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2008/10/predicates-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot that goes on behind the scenes to determine how a query is executed, but in this situation I would *expect* for it to filter on the field1 first.  Note that this isn't a guarantee - the query optimizer can make some strange choices now and then.  Additionally, you can improve your chances by using the '=' operator rather than the 'LIKE' operator.

Answer (score 1):

`mysp` can't be a stored procedure. It has to be a user defined function (which you should have qualified with its schema name, by the way). A user defined function is restricted to be side-effect free and should adhere to some rules. Essentially, SQL Server will combine the query and execute it as a single module with a single execution plan. It's not procedural function calling as you might expect. SQL describes what to do, not how to do it and the query optimizer will generate a plan that responds to your complete query, not each part of it separately. The same is true for views.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Management Studio (for 2008 and I think 2005), you can tell it to show you the execution plan. Press Control-M in the query window. Then execute the query. That will show you the detail.

Answer (score 0):

Is `myfunc` just a complex calculation or does the return value change frequently. I am wondering because if it doesn't change that often and this is a frequently executed query, it may be better design to have an after insert trigger calculate the value and store it in the table as a separate column. Then you don't have to worry about which order things are evaluated in. The query may even run faster, especially if you have an index on both columns.